# What are the ways to change the banner/carousel on frequently updated sites

Tags: javascript, html, view, templating

Suppose there is a carousel of latest deals on my website. I need to update the images in the carousel frequently(say every second day) due to new offers. One way I can do this is by fetching the details of the offers(banner_img_url, product link, title, etc.) using an ajax request in JSON format and then create the elements dynamically.

I am wondering what are the other ways to update this portion of the page in any other probably better way. I have just heard of server side tempelating also but don't have good idea.

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As I think the way you are using is better for your requirement. If I would implement such functionality, definitely I will also use your way. AJAX request from server side scripting is better way for displaying dynamic content in website.

Thanks...